# Had an issue this morning with my external HD

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive

I have a Western Digital MyBook external hard drive.  I've had it for at least 2 years, perhaps 3.  I leave it on 24/7.  This morning, when I turned on my Windows 7 PC, it couldn't find MyBook.  And I could see by the lights on the MyBook, that it wasn't doing anything, either.  It didn't show up in my Network.  I cycled the power on the MyBook, and it became available on my network and visible/accessible from my machine.

So I've got a few questions about this.  How can I determine the health of an external HD?  Is there some sort of utility on the MyBook which I can run from Windows, to see about it's health?  Second question, what's the life expectency of Western Digital MyBooks?

Comment: Can you remove the drive from the enclosure and hook it up to your computer or is that not a possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your MyBook is using an eSATA connection to your computer (which I don't think the MyBooks have, or at least didn't 2-3 years ago?), you're not going to find a generic solution for checking on the hard drive's health (you can run SMART tests via an eSATA connection, but not via USB, FireWire, nor network).

Check Western Digital's support section of their website for your particular model, see if they have any diagnostic software you can download. Alternatively, contact their technical support and ask them about it directly.

Also, backup backup backup! You should always have your data backed up, but most especially if there's even the slightest possibility that your drive is starting to fail on you you should immediately back up everything you don't want to lose.